# How to make convert this long assignment statement into a function in Amibroker?

Tags: amibroker

I have this long assignment statement in Amibroker.

```
num_times_above = iif(Ref(CLOSE, -0)>Ref(CLOSE, -4) , 1, 0)
                    + iif(Ref(CLOSE, -1)>Ref(CLOSE, -4), 1, 0)
                    + iif(Ref(CLOSE, -2)>Ref(CLOSE, -4), 1, 0)
                    + iif(Ref(CLOSE, -3)>Ref(CLOSE, -4), 1, 0)
                    + iif(Ref(CLOSE, -4)>Ref(CLOSE, -4), 1, 0)
                    ;
```

I would like to convert this long statement into a generic function that accepts a parameter n.

```
function get_num_times_above(n)
{
  //code
}
```

The code on top is for the case when `n == 4`. I am stuck at this seemingly simple problem because of the array format used in Amibroker.

if `n == 3`, the equivalent code will be;

```
num_times_above = iif(Ref(CLOSE, -0)>Ref(CLOSE, -3) , 1, 0)
                    + iif(Ref(CLOSE, -1)>Ref(CLOSE, -3), 1, 0)
                    + iif(Ref(CLOSE, -2)>Ref(CLOSE, -3), 1, 0)
                    + iif(Ref(CLOSE, -3)>Ref(CLOSE, -3), 1, 0)
                    ;
```

I am using Amibroker ver6.28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
function get_num_times_above(n)
{
    num_times_above = 0;
    refn = Ref(C, -n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
        num_times_above += Ref(C, -i)>refn;
    return num_times_above;
}
```

Credit goes to fxshrat who provided the answer here.

https://forum.amibroker.com/t/how-to-make-convert-this-long-assignment-statement-into-a-function/7181/2